# How to write a data in particular address in C

Tags: c++, c

I need to write 0x00001234 in the address 0x8000000, is it possible in C?

Comment: That address probably won't be valid for writing to. You may be able to force it to exist, for instance with [`mmap` and `MAP_FIXED`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mmap.html) if you are using a POSIX OS.

Comment: @BoBTFish Maybe he is programming for a microcontroller.

Comment: What do you need this for? And why? And with what?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you work with hardware register in embedded system then standard way is:

```
int volatile * const p_reg = (int *) 0x8000000;
*p_reg = 0x1234;
```

You can have a lot of problems with optimizing compiler, if you omit **volatile**

Answer (score 8):

You can, but you will have a segfault 99.9999..9% of the time because your program won't have access on this memory address.

```
int *nb = (int *) 0x8000000;
*nb = 0x00001234;
```

Comment: It depends also on your linker script (you can omit some RAM banks and use them manually), though it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Well if this is a beginner assignment in a c class i suspect it is turbo or borland c where you are programming in 16 bit environment with segment offset address scheme. In that case using an **int * far ptr**, with *far* being the pointer type to access address out of your current segment would be used. 0xb8000000 used to be the starting address of text mode video memory.

i.e.

```
int far * p = 0xB8000000;
*p = 'A'; // This would actually print char 'A' on screen
*(p+1) = <some number>; // this would determine the color of char A
```

Note that this used to be 16 bit programming. So a normal int * would be 16 bit and hence cannot access beyond current segment of memory.

We used to implement printf of our own by directly writing to video mem. This was a class assignment in c programming course over a decade ago. May be it matches your scenario.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12826195/986760) explanation might be helpful as well

Comment: This is not a begineer assignment ..:)

Comment: Agreed, not a very 'beginner one' given in the start of a programming course. But it certainly does not hold a real world need, even at that time. However, it helps to understand memory, pointers and being able to write functions ourselves. Hence it is more of an academic use.